# List Of Nouns That Change Meaning With Gender (e.g. der See vs. die See)

Tags: gender

For far I've aware of:

- die Band (music) vs. das Band (ribbon)
- der See (lake) vs. die See (sea/ocean)
- die Steuer (tax) vs. das Steuer (steering wheel)

What others are out there?

Comment: While I consider this question as off-topic (coverd by references), here is a procedure: Start with [this list](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Homonyme) and eliminate non-nouns and same gender homonyms (if really desired).

Comment: **Bitte hier keine weiteren Vorschläge als Kommentar posten.** Neue Wörter können als **[edit](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/40769/edit)** in die CW-Antwort eingefügt werden. Für Diskussionsbedarf wurde ein eigener Chatraum eingerichtet: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70717/discussion-on-answer-by-hubert-scholnast-list-of-nouns-that-change-meaning-with

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70719/discussion-on-question-by-jack-kinsella-list-of-nouns-that-change-meaning-with-g).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Achtel**

  - die Achtel: kurze Musiknote
  - das Achtel: der achte Teil eines Ganzen
- **Alpaka**

  - das Alpaka: ein höckerloses Kamel aus der Familie der Lamas
  - der Alpaka: dichtes glänzendes Gewebe (ursprünglich aus Alpakawolle)
  - die Alpaka: recycelte Wolle (aus: *das Alpaka*)
- **Aviso**

  - der Aviso: kleines, schnelles Kriegsschiff zur Nachrichtenübermittlung
  - das Aviso: schriftliche Ankündigung einer Warensendung
- **Balg**

  - der Balg: gefalteter Hohlkörper mit veränderlichem Volumen (z.B. Blasebalg oder der Balg zwischen Linse und Fotoplatte bei historischen Fotoapparaten)
  - das Balg: unartiges Kind, nicht gewolltes Kind (beides auch: *der Balg*)
- **Ballerina**

  - der Ballerina: flacher Damenschuh (wird meist im Plural verwendet)
  - die Ballerina: Balletttänzerin
- **Band**

  - der Band: ein Buch, das Teil eines größeren Werkes ist
  - die Band: (englische Aussprache) eine Musikgruppe
  - das Band: langes schmales Stück Stoff, mit dem etwas gebunden wird
- **Bauer**

  - der Bauer: Landwirt
  - das Bauer: Vogelkäfig (auch: der Bauer)
- **Beige**

  - das Beige: sehr heller brauner Farbton
  - die Beige: Stoß, Stapel (z.B. Holzbeige = Holzstoß)
- **Biest**

  - der Biest: erste Milch eines Rindes
  - das Biest: widerwärtiges Tier, hinterhältige Frau
- **Blei**

  - der Blei: ein Fisch (Karpfen), Kurzform für *Bleistift*
  - das Blei: ein Metall
- **Bock**

  - der Bock: Männchen vieler Tierarten, vierbeiniges klobiges Gestell, Lust (auf etwas einen Bock haben), sexuell aktiver Mann, hoher Schuh oder Stiefel (in Österreich)
  - das Bock: Bier mit viel Stammwürze
- **Bolzen**

  - der Bolzen: Geschoss einer Armbrust, Verbindungsstück aus Holz oder Metall
  - das Bolzen: Fußballspielen
- **Braten**

  - der Braten: im Ofen zubereitetes Fleisch
  - das Braten: Vorgang, bei dem etwas gebraten wird
- **Bulle**

  - der Bulle: Stier, Polizist
  - die Bulle: kreisrundes Siegel, Dokument mit einem solchen Siegel, päpstlicher Erlass
- **Bund**

  - der Bund: ein Zusammenschluss mehrerer Länder, höchste politische Verwaltungsebene, Verstärkung am Ende eines Rohres, oberer Abschluss einer Hose, die Seitenbindung am Rücken eines Buches
  - das Bund: ein Bündel (etwas das zusammengebunden ist) (z.B. ein Bund Schnittlauch)
- **Center**

  - der Center: Spieler im Zentrum des Spielfeldes (z.B. Basketball)
  - das Center: Gebäude mit mehreren Verkaufsgeschäften (Shoppingcenter)
- **Demo**

  - die Demo: Kurz für *Demonstration* (Versammlung zur Meinungskundgebung oder Geräteaufbau zu Vorführungszwecken oder Mini-Software-Variante zum Zweck des Ausprobierens)
  - das Demo: Kurz für *Demoaufnahme* (eine Art Visitenkarte für Schauspieler und Musiker)
- **Domino**

  - der Domino: Maskenkostüm mit Kapuze und weitern Ärmeln
  - das Domino: Spiel mit flachen Steinen, die nach einem Zahlensystem aneinandergelegt werden müssen
- **Elbe**

  - der Elbe: ein Nachtgeist
  - die Elbe: ein Fluss
- **Elf**

  - der Elf: keltisch/germanische Märchen- und Sagengestalt
  - die Elf: die Zahl 11, Fußballmannschaft
- **Erbe**

  - der Erbe: eine Person, die etwas erbt oder geerbt hat
  - das Erbe: das, was vererbt wird
- **Erkenntnis**

  - die Erkenntnis: Einsicht, Verständnis
  - das Erkenntnis: Urteil eines österreichischen Verwaltungsgerichts
- **Finne**

  - der Finne: eine männliche Person, die aus Finnland stammt
  - die Finne: geschlechtslose Jugendform eines Bandwurms, ein Pickel, Rückenflosse eines Hais oder Wals (oder ähnlich geformte Spurstabilisatoren bei z.B. Surfbrettern), spitze Seite eines Hammers
- **Flipflop**

  - der Flipflop: ein Schuh, der nur aus einer Sohle und einer Zehenschlaufe besteht
  - das Flipflop: eine elektronische Schaltung (bistabiler Multivibrator)
- **Flur**

  - der Flur: länglicher Eingangsbereich eines Gebäudes
  - die Flur: landwirtschaftlich genutzte Fläche
- **Funken**

  - der Funken: kleines glühendes Teilchen, das durch die Luft fliegt, sichtbare elektrische Entladung
  - das Funken: drahtlose Nachrichtenübermittlung
- **Gang**

  - der Gang: Gehende Fortbewegung, langgezogener Verbindungsraum, Schaltstufe eines Getriebes, Teil einer Speisenfolge, Verlauf einer Handlung
  - die Gang: (englische Aussprache): eine kriminelle Bande
- **Gehalt**

  - der Gehalt: Anteil einer Substanz in einer Mischung
  - das Gehalt: Einkommen, Verdienst
- **Gift**

  - die Gift: etwas, das man jemandem weitergibt (veraltet. Heute nur mehr in *die Mitgift*)
  - das Gift: gesundheitsgefährdende oder sogar tödliche Substanz
  - der Gift: Ärger, Zorn
- **Golf**

  - der Golf: Meeresbucht, Automodell
  - das Golf: Rasensport
- **Heide**

  - der Heide: Jemand, der weder Jude noch Christ ist
  - die Heide: Landschaft mit vielen Gräsern und Sträuchern aber wenig Bäumen
- **Hefe**

  - die Hefe: Arten einzelliger Pilze, verwendet u.a. beim Backen und Bierbrauen
  - das Hefe: Kurzbezeichnung für *Hefeweizen*, ein Weizenbier ("Ein Hefe bitte")
- **Hut**

  - der Hut: Kopfbedeckung
  - die Hut: Wacht (nur mehr in der Redensart »auf der Hut sein« und in Zusammensetzungen, z.B. *die Obhut*)
- **Irre**

  - der Irre/die Irre: an einer Psychose erkrankte Person (m/f)
  - (in) die Irre: verirren
- **Jura**

  - der Jura: ein Erdzeitalter
  - die Jura: (nur Plural, nur in Deutschland und der Schweiz): Rechtswissenschaften (in Österreich: *das Jus*, nur Singular)
- **Kaki**

  - der Kaki: hellbrauner Stoff
  - das Kaki: eine Farbe
  - die Kaki: eine Frucht
- **Kaper**

  - der Kaper: Ein Schiff, das in Kriegszeiten das Recht hat, feindliche Schiffe zu kapern
  - die Kaper: in Salzlake eingelegte Knospe des Kapernstrauchs
- **Kiefer**

  - der Kiefer: Knochen im Schädel
  - die Kiefer: ein Nadelbaum, ein Fluss in Tirol und Bayern (fließt durch Kiefersfelden)
- **Kiwi**

  - der Kiwi: flugunfähiger Vogel aus Neuseeland
  - die Kiwi: essbare Frucht des chinesischen Strahlengriffels
- **Koch**

  - der Koch: Beruf (Zubereitung von Speisen)
  - das Koch: Brei (in Bayern und Österreich)
- **Koks**

  - der Koks: Brennstoff, der durch trockene Destillation aus Kohle hergestellt wird
  - das Koks: Kokain
- **Koma**

  - die Koma: ein optischer Abbildungsfehler, gasförmige Hülle um den Kern eines Kometen
  - das Koma: tiefe Bewusstlosigkeit
- **Kontroverse**

  - der Kontroverse: Laienbruder eines katholischen Ordens
  - die Kontroverse: eine Aussage, die im Gegensatz zu einer anderen Aussage steht
- **Koppel**

  - die Koppel: Pferdeweide
  - das Koppel: Gürtel zur Befestigung von Werkzeug, Waffen oder Munition
- **Korn**

  - der Korn: ein Schnaps
  - das Korn: Getreide, einzelner Samen, kleines rundes Objekt, Zielvorrichtung auf einem Gewehr (Kimme und Korn), Auflösungsvermögen von Fotomaterial
- **Kölsch**

  - der Kölsch: zweifarbig gewürfelter Stoff aus Baumwolle
  - das Kölsch: obergäriges Bier
- **Kristall**

  - der Kristall: homogener Körper mit periodischer molekularer Struktur
  - das Kristall: geschliffenes Glas
- **Kunde**

  - der Kunde: eine Person, die etwas kauft oder eine Dienstleitung in Anspruch nimmt
  - die Kunde: eine Nachricht
- **Lachs**

  - der Lachs: ein Fisch
  - das Lachs: eine Farbe
- **Lama**

  - der Lama: tibetisch-buddhistischer Mönch
  - das Lama: eine Kamelgattung
- **Laster**

  - der Laster: ein LKW
  - das Laster: eine schlechte Angewohnheit
- **Leiter**

  - der Leiter: Eine Person die andere anleitet; eine Substanz, die elektrischen Strom oder Wärme durchfließen lässt
  - die Leiter: Aufstiegshilfe mit Sprossen
- **Lob**

  - der Lob: (Aussprache mit kurzem o) Schlagart beim Tennis
  - das Lob: (Aussprache mit langem o) anerkennende Worte
- **Mähre**

  - der Mähre: männliche Person, die aus Mähren stammt
  - die Mähre: heruntergekommenes Pferd
- **Mangel**

  - der Mangel: Zustand, bei dem etwas nicht in ausreichender Menge vorhanden ist
  - die Mangel: Gerät mit zwei Walzen, um etwas flachzudrücken oder auszuwringen (z.B. nasse Wäsche)
- **Mark**

  - die Mark: ein politisches Verwaltungsgebiet (z.B. Steiermark); eine alte Währungseinheit
  - das Mark: das weiche Innere von Knochen und Pflanzenstängeln; Obst- oder Gemüsepüree
- **Massel**

  - der Massel: Glück (in Österreich und Bayern: *das Massel*)
  - die Massel: gegossener Metallblock (z.B. Kopf eines Hammers)
- **Mast**

  - der Mast: ein großer Pfahl, an dem Fahnen oder Segel montiert sind
  - die Mast: Fütterung von Tieren
- **Mensch**

  - der Mensch: Lebewesen der Gattung Homo (heute nur mehr eine Art: Homo sapiens)
  - das Mensch: junge Frau (oft abwertend gemeint) (in Österreich und Bayern, veraltet)
- **Messer**

  - der Messer: Person, die etwas misst
  - das Messer: Schneidewerkzeug
- **Mikado**

  - der Mikado: ehemaliger Titel für den Kaiser von Japan
  - das Mikado: Geschicklichkeitsspiel mit Holzstäbchen
- **Mohr**

  - der Mohr: veraltete Bezeichnung für Menschen mit dunkler Hautfarbe
  - das Mohr: schwarzes Metallpulver (in der Pharmazie)
- **Moment**

  - der Moment: kurze Zeitspanne
  - das Moment: Ursache einer Handlung, eine tangential wirkende Kraft
- **Ohm**

  - der Ohm: Bruder der Mutter
  - das Ohm: physikalische Einheit des elektrischen Widerstands
- **Orange**

  - die Orange: Apfelsine, eine Südfrucht
  - das Orange: Farbton zwischen rot und gelb
- **Otter**

  - der Otter: Am Wasser lebendes Pelztier (Marder)
  - die Otter: eine Giftschlange
- **Partikel**

  - die Partikel: *kath. Kirche* Teilchen der Hostie, Kreuzreliquie; *Sprachw.* unflektierbare Wortart, z. B. Präposition
  - das (auch die) Partikel: *Physik* Elementarteilchen
- **Pik**

  - der Pik: Berggipfel; Groll, den man auf jemand hat
  - das Pik: Kartenfarbe bei französischen Spielkarten
- **Plastik**

  - die Plastik: dreidimensionales Kunstwerk, das nicht durch Weghauen von Material entstanden ist; chirurgische Nachbildung eines Körperteils
  - das Plastik: Kunststoff
- **Positiv**

  - der Positiv: Grundstufe bei der Steigerung von Adjektiven (Positiv - Komparativ - Superlativ, z.B. groß - größer - am größten)
  - das Positiv: kleine Standorgel ohne Pedale; ein Foto, das Farben und Helligkeiten wie beim Original zeigt (als Gegensatz zum Negativ)
- **Primat**

  - der Primat: Menschenaffe
  - das Primat: bevorzugte Stallung, höchstes Gewalt in der Kirche (beides auch: *der Primat*)
- **Quark**

  - der Quark: Milchprodukt, v.a. aus ausgefälltem Milcheiweiß (in Österreich: Topfen)
  - das Quark: Elementarteilchen, aus denen nach gängiger physikalischer Lehre die Hadronen (z.B. Protonen und Neutronen) bestehen
- **Regen**

  - der Regen: flüssiger Niederschlag
  - das Regen: leichte Bewegung
- **Reis**

  - der Reis: Getreide
  - das Reis: dünner Zweig
- **Rentier**

  - der Rentier (franz. [rɛnˈtjeː]): eine Person, die von regelmäßigen Zahlungen aus angelegtem Kapital oder der Verpachtung von Land lebt (Wikipedia)
  - das Rentier: eine in den Tundren lebende Hirschart (Wikipedia)
- **Ried**

  - der Ried: der Rüde (veraltet)
  - die Ried: Stück von der Rippe eines Ochsen (in Österreich)
  - das Ried: schilfartiges Gewächs; Röhricht; landwirtschaftliche Fläche, auf der Wein angebaut wird
- **Riff**

  - der Riff: melodische Phrase mit hohen Wiedererkennungswert in der Popmusik (auch: *das Riff*)
  - das Riff: Erhebung im Meer, die bis Nahe an die Wasseroberfläche (manchmal sogar darüber) reicht
- **Riss**

  - der Riss: Stelle, an der etwas gerissen ist
  - die Riss: ein Fluss in Oberschwaben, Zufluss der Donau
- **Scharlach**

  - der Scharlach: fiebrige Erkrankung, rot gefärbter Stoff
  - das Scharlach: eine roter Farbton
- **Schild**

  - der Schild: Eine meist gewölbte Platte, mit der man sich vor Angriffen (z.B. durch Pfeile) schützt
  - das Schild: Etikett, Träger einer Aufschrift
- **Schoß**

  - der Schoß: weiblicher Unterleib; Teil der sitzenden Körpers (Unterleib + Oberschenkel); Teil der Bekleidung, der Hüfte und Gesäß bedeckt (z.B. beim Frack)
  - die Schoß: Damenrock (in Österreich)
- **Schütze**

  - der Schütze: jemand, der schießt (mit einer Waffe oder einem Ball), militärischer Dienstgrad, Sternzeichen
  - die Schütze: ein Schuber, mit dem der Wasserfluss bei einer Schleuse geregelt wird. [Strittig, [siehe Chat]](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41918915#41918915)
- **See**

  - der See: stehendes Binnengewässer (Süßwasser)
  - die See: Meer, Ozean (Salzwasser)
- **Sekret**

  - die Sekret: das stille Gebet des Priesters während der Messe
  - das Sekret: flüssige Absonderung eines Lebewesens
- **Steuer**

  - das Steuer: Vorrichtung um ein Fahrzeug zu lenken
  - die Steuer: Abgabe, die an eine Verwaltungsbehörde zu entrichten ist
- **Stift**

  - der Stift: Schreibgerät, Nagel, Lehrling, männliches Kind, Stachel, Stängel, Dorn
  - das Stift: Kloster samt Landbesitz
  - die Stift: rechtlicher Fachbegriff in Österreich und Bayern (veraltet)
- **Store**

  - der Store: ein Laden
  - der/die Store: eine Bedeckung
- **Tatar**

  - der Tatar: Angehöriger eines turksprachigen Volksstammes
  - das Tatar: gewürztes, mageres Rinderhackfleisch, das roh verzehrt wird
- **Tau**

  - der Tau: Luftfeuchtigkeit, die z.B. an Blättern kondensiert
  - das Tau: dickes Seil; griechischer Buchstabe
- **Teil**

  - der Teil: z.B. der Teil eines Buchs/Films, der dritte Teil, der (An-)Teil vom Ganzen
  - das Teil: z.B. Ersatzteil, Bauteil, eines Puzzles
- **Tor**

  - der Tor: weltfremder Mensch
  - das Tor: Portal, Zugang
- **Trial**

  - der Trial: Numerus, der eine Dreizahl ausdrückt (linguistischer Begriff)
  - das Trial: (englische Aussprache) Geschicklichkeitsprüfung für Motorradfahrer
- **Trikot**

  - der Trikot: speziell gewirkter Stoff
  - das Trikot: farbiges Sporthemd
- **Verdienst**

  - der Verdienst: Bezahlung, Einkommen
  - das Verdienst: vergangene Tätigkeit, die Anerkennung verdient
- **Viertel**

  - die Viertel: Musiknote
  - das Viertel: der vierte Teil eines Ganzen
- **Virus**

  - das Virus: krankheitserregendes Partikel
  - der Virus: Computervirus (Schadsoftware, die sich selbsttätig verbreitet)
- **Vorsatz**

  - der Vorsatz: Absicht; der Satz vor einem anderen Satz
  - das Vorsatz: das Papierblatt, das den Buchblock mit dem Einband verbindet
- **Wagen**

  - der Wagen: Transportmittel
  - das Wagen: das Riskieren
- **Wehe**

  - die Wehe: Kontraktion der Gebärmutter unmittelbar vor einer Geburt; vom Wind zusammengewehte Anhäufung (Schnee, Sand); Windbö
  - das Wehe: das seelische Leid, seelischer Schmerz (auch: das Weh)
- **Wehr**

  - die Wehr: Kampfeinheit, Abwehrwaffe
  - das Wehr: Anlage, um Fließgewässer aufzustauen
- **Weise**

  - der Weise: kluger Mann
  - die Weise: die Art, die Melodie oder kluge Frau
- **Weizen**

  - der Weizen: eine Getreideart
  - das Weizen: Bier, das aus Weizen (statt sonst aus Gerste) gebraut wurde
- **Wetter**

  - der Wetter: eine Person, die wettet
  - das Wetter: aktueller Zustand des Klimas, die Luft in einem Bergwerk
- **Zelt**

  - der Zelt: flacher Kuchen (z.B. Lebzelt = Lebkuchen), Passgang (z.B. bei Pferden)
  - das Zelt: textile Behausung
- **Zink**

  - der Zink: historisches Blasinstrument aus Holz oder Elfenbein
  - das Zink: ein Metall
- **Zoll**

  - der Zoll: Abgabe für die Ein- oder Ausfuhr von Waren; Behörde, die diese Abgabe einhebt
  - das Zoll: altes Längenmaß (ca. 2,5 cm)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70717/discussion-on-answer-by-hubert-scholnast-list-of-nouns-that-change-meaning-with).

Comment: **Bitte unter diese Antwort keine weiteren Kommentare schreiben.** Neue Wörter können von jedermann einfach per [edit] eingefügt werden. Für hoffentlich weitere lebhafte Diskussionen  zu diesem Thema wurde ein [eigener Raum eingerichtet](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70717/discussion-on-answer-by-hubert-scholnast-list-of-nouns-that-change-meaning-with).